# paper-dropdown-menu this._setValue(value);

Tags: polymer-1.0

i'm trying to understand the Polymer paper-dropdown-menu element but on line 355 there is a line

```
this._setValue(value);
```

I've searched the code and the code of the behaviours but can't figure out where the method _setValue is coming from?

can someone help me understand?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `_setX(val)` method is added by Polymer element constructor dynamically for read-only properties.

```js
 Polymer({
   is: 'paper-dropdown-menu',
   properties: {
     value: {           
       readOnly: true
     }
   },
   someFunction: function() {
     this._setValue('x');

     // this will fail
     this.value = 'x';
   }
 });
```

See the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#read-only) for reference.

Comment: Thanks Thomasz, I didn't search in that part of the documentation, gratis help